# 401 spotify api spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spotify

i wanto to make a microservice that he verify a song by spotify api , i have create a new project and i get the client id and the client secret , in my spring boot microservice i have created two classes one service to check the authentication and the second the controler to verify the songs , but when i want to check the song it's not give me any response , the second thing that when i access to the url in the browser it's redirect me to localhost:8080/login and with signin forms , always i get 401 error :
app.properties:

```
spotify.client-id=******
spotify.client-secret=****
spotify.authorization-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
spotify.token-uri=https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
spotify.scope=user-read-private,user-read-email
spotify.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8082/callback
```

the configuration class :

```
 @Configuration
public class SpotifyConfig {

@Value("${spotify.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${spotify.client-secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${spotify.redirect-uri}")
private URI redirectUri;

@Bean
public SpotifyApi spotifyApi() {
    SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .build();
    return spotifyApi;
}

@Bean
ClientCredentialsRequest clientCredentialsRequest(SpotifyApi spotifyApi) {
    ClientCredentialsRequest clientCredentialsRequest = spotifyApi.clientCredentials()
            .build();
    return clientCredentialsRequest;
}

@Bean
SpotifyApi authorizedSpotifyApi(SpotifyApi spotifyApi, ClientCredentialsRequest 
clientCredentialsRequest) throws IOException, SpotifyWebApiException, 
org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException {
    ClientCredentials clientCredentials = clientCredentialsRequest.execute();
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(clientCredentials.getAccessToken());
    return spotifyApi;
}
```

}
the controller class:
@RestController
public class VerificarCancionController {
@Autowired
private SpotifyApi spotifyApi;

```
@GetMapping("/verificar-cancion/{nombreCancion}")
public ResponseEntity<String> verificarCancion(@PathVariable String nombreCancion) {
    try {
        // Search for a track by name
        SearchTracksRequest searchRequest = spotifyApi.searchTracks("track:" + nombreCancion)
                .build();
        Track[] tracks = searchRequest.execute().getItems();

        if (tracks.length > 0) {
            // Get the first track from the search results
            String trackId = tracks[0].getId();
            GetTrackRequest trackRequest = spotifyApi.getTrack(trackId)
                    .build();
            Track track = trackRequest.execute();

            // Return the URL of the track's image
            return ResponseEntity.ok(track.getAlbum().getImages()[0].getUrl());
        } else {
            // If the song is not found on Spotify, return an error response
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("La canción no se encontró 
 en Spotify.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any exceptions and return an error response
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Ocurrió un error 
al verificar la canción.");
    }
}
```